# Replacement for deprecated attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation function

Tags: ios, swift

I have been using the `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` function to change the orientation of some ViewController when the user presses a button. However, as of iOS 16, this function has been officially deprecated.

What can I use as the replacement?

Answer (score 1):

this can be done in two ways.

personally I prefer this way

**1.keep this function in AppDelegate to handle the orientation(this is must)**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all
}
```

**2. in which ViewController you want the force orientation, go to that view controller and add these lines in the variable declaring section**

```
var forceLandscape: Bool = false

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
           forceLandscape ? .landscape : .portrait
}
```

we will be updating the **forceLandscape** so it will get updated, then the **supportedInterfaceOrientations** also will get updated

**3. Here we are setting the trigger for updating the forceLandscape (we can add these lines of code inside button action for handling IOS 16 force roatation)**

```
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            self.forceLandscape = true
            guard let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else { return }
            self.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {
                windowScene.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscapeRight)){
                        error in
                        print(error)
                        print(windowScene.effectiveGeometry)
                }
            })
```

this will update the **forceLandscape**, so it will check the orientation and update according to it

Comment: This answer is incomplete since the self is missing.

Answer (score 0):

According to release note: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-16-release-notes?changes=lat__8_1
I think you may have to use **setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterface**.

> **Deprecations**
> [UIViewController shouldAutorotate] has been deprecated is no longer supported. [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation] has been deprecated and replaced with [UIViewController setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations].
> **Workaround**: Apps relying on shouldAutorotate should reflect their preferences using the view controllers supportedInterfaceOrientations. If the supported orientations change, use `-[UIViewController setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterface

I think you may have to use **setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterface**.